# Is there a way to create an instance of a subclass from its base class? I need it for my custom wrapper of TcpClient/Listener

Tags: vb.net, casting, wrapper, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm writing classes which wrap around the `TcpListener` and `TcpClient` classes in VB. Currently here is my wrapper of the `TcpListener` class:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text

Public Class XXXTcpServer : Inherits TcpListener

    Public name As String

    Public clients As List(Of TcpClient)

    Public maxClients As Integer = -1

    ...

    Sub New(Optional ByVal name As String = "", Optional ByVal port As Int32 = 30000, Optional ByVal localAddr As IPAddress = Nothing)

        MyBase.New(If(localAddr, IPAddress.Any), Math.Max(IPEndPoint.MinPort, Math.Min(IPEndPoint.MaxPort, port)))

        Me.name = name
    End Sub

    Function acceptRequests() As Integer

        Dim accepted As Integer = 0

        While Pending() AndAlso (maxClients = -1 OrElse clients.Count < maxClients)

            Dim client As TcpClient = AcceptTcpClient()

            clients.Add(client)

            accepted += 1
        End While

        Return accepted
    End Function
End Class
```

However, it isn't a perfect wrapper because `clients` is a `List(Of TcpClient)` rather than a `List(Of XXXTcpClient)` (which is my wrapper class for `TcpClient`). I would like to make it the latter as the `XXXTcpClient` class has properties which stores additional information about the client which is needed.

The problem is that the `AcceptTcpClient()` method in the `acceptRequests()` function returns a `TcpClient` and I need to convert `client` into a `XXXTcpClient` in some way.

I was hoping for a solution like adding the following initialiser to the `XXXTcpClient` class:

```
Public Class XXXTcpClient : Inherits TcpClient

    ...

    Sub New(ByVal client As TcpClient)

        Me = client

        ...
        'Initialise all non-inherited variables to default values
        ...

    End Sub
End Class
```

and then using this in the `acceptRequests()` function instead:

```
Dim client As New XXXTcpClient(AcceptTcpClient())
```

but of course, that doesn't work.

Searching online seems to tell me that this is impossible to do, so I would appreciate a suggested solution to this problem.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I should've posted here or to code review, so please tell me if it should be moved

Comment: Code Review wants to see your working code, and give you better ways to do what it does... as far as I can see, this would be off-topic on CR.

Comment: Do either of your XXX classes really need to inherit from the TcpListener/Client classes, or could they just contain instances of the wrapped classes?

Comment: @Mark That's a possibility, although I prefer inheritance as the methods and properties are carried through which means I don't have to do something like `XXX.client.MethodOrProp` to call them

Comment: Instead of `Me = client`, try setting all the properties.  It appears as though [TCPClient.Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.client(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) is the primary one.

Comment: @TnTinMn Well I didn't actually consider that before because I was worried something might not carry through properly, but now I look at the documentation it does seem possible... I guess this probably is the best solution.

Comment: Is there some method which does this for me without me having to write out each property? Looking into it, I still can't find much that's helpful or even something explaining why VB doesn't allow something like this..

Comment: Looks similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692348/creating-an-instance-of-derived-class-through-the-base-class-without-hardcoding

Comment: I've never used them, but have you heard of "extension methods"? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396