# Why does VB disallow type conversion from parent to subclass?

Tags: class, inheritance, type-conversion

I have already asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962425/vb-is-there-a-way-to-create-an-instance-of-a-subclass-from-its-base-class-i-ne?noredirect=1#comment65281736_38962425) where I basically require an instance of a base class to be converted into a subclass (or a new instance of the subclass to be created using the instance of the base class' properties). The conclusion seems to be that the best way to do this is to manually assign every property I need to transfer in the constructor of the base class.

While this is feasible in some cases, it certainly is not when there are many properties to transfer, or when the base class is subject to change — every time you add a property to the base class, the constructor needs to be changed too, so this solutions is inelegant.

I have searched online, and can't see any reason for why this kind of type-casting isn't implemented. The arguments I have seen so far describe this operation to 'not make any sense' (making a minivan from a car was an analogy I saw), question what to do about the non-inherited variables in the subclass, or claim that there must be some better solution for what was trying to be achieved.

As far as I can see, the operation doesn't need to 'make sense' as long as it's useful, so that isn't much of a good reason. What's wrong with adding a few more properties (and perhaps methods/overriding them) to change an instance into a subclass? In the case of the non-inherited variables, that can simply be solved by allowing this kind of type-cast only a constructor is added to the subclass or by just simply setting them to their default values. After all, constructors usually call `MyBase.New(...)` anyway. What's the difference between using the constructor of the base (essentially creating a new instance of the base) and using an instance which is already initialised? Lastly, I don't think the third argument is well-justified — there are times when all of the other solutions are inelegant.

So finally, is there any other reason for why this kind of casting isn't allowed, and is there an elegant way to circumvent this?

Edit:

Since I don't know a lot about this topic, I think I meant to say 'convert' rather than 'cast'. I'll also add an example to show what I'm trying to succeed. The conversion would only be allowed at the initialisation of the Subclass:

```
Class BaseClass

Dim x as Integer
Dim y as Integer

End Class


Class Subclass1 : Inherits BaseClass

    Dim z as Integer

    Sub New(Byval value As Integer)
        'Standard initialisation method

        MyBase.New()

        z = value
    End Sub

    Sub New(Byval value As Integer, Byval baseInstance As BaseClass)
        'Type conversion from base class to subclass

        baseInstance.passAllproperties()
'This assigns all properties of baseInstance belonging to BaseClass to Me.
'Properties not in BaseClass (eg. if baseInstance is Subclass2) are ignored.

        z = value
    End Sub
End Class


Class Subclass2 : Inherits BaseClass

    Dim v As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: You need to get a better understanding of inheritance and polymorphism. You can't cast a base to a descendant because it usually isn't possible to do so. How can you cast an animal to a horse and treat it like one, when that animal may be a cat or a seal? Cats and seals object strenuously when you attempt to put a saddle and bridle on them and ride them around your yard. If you're finding yourself needing to do this, it's a sign your classes are poorly designed or implemented.

Comment: @KenWhite I disagree. What's wrong with the descendant asking for an instance of a base at initialisation to use as a template?

Comment: That's not what your question asks, though. Your question asks about the **base** being cast to a **descendant**, which is the **exact opposite**. It's fine for a descendant to ask for a parent (base) instance; it's done regularly when calling a base  constructor, for instance. You've asked about doing the opposite, which is  where you failed.

Comment: @KenWhite I was a bit confused about my terminology, and mean "convert" rather than cast. But how are they exact opposites? And also, you imply that it's possible to do... how?

Comment: A descendant **inherits** from the base. There's no *conversion* or *casting* involved. You need to get your head around the basics of OOP. Children **inherit** from their parents, which means that a descendant already has the contents of the base class. You don't have to convert a horse to an animal - by being a horse, it already **is** an animal. You don't *require an instance of the base to become a subclass*, because the *subclass already contains the base*.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes I understand that. But I want a new instance of the descendant initialised using an already initialised instance of the base and that's what I meant by conversion. I know it isn't required, but there are cases where I actually need it. Eg. A method I'm using returns an instance of the base but I need to then create an instance of the descendant using it.

Comment: You can't *convert* an instance of the base into a descendant. What part of *you can't magically turn a base animal into a horse, because it may not be a horse in the first place* is it you're not grasping here? You have to create a new descendant and initialize it from the fields of the base. Or, better yet, fix your code that returns the base instance to properly use polymorphism.

Comment: @KenWhite Ok, maybe not directly convert. But just simply an instance of a descendant made using properties from a base instance — that's what I'm asking for here. Unfortunately, I cannot 'fix my code' that returns the base instance because it is not my code — I wouldn't be having this problem in the first place in the specific example if it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.Reflection` to iterate over properties and fields of the base class and apply them to the derived class. This example includes a single public property and single public field, but will also work with multiple *private/protected* properties and fields. You can paste the entire example into a new console application to test it.

```vb
Imports System.Reflection

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim p As New Parent
        p.Property1 = "abc"
        p.Field1 = "def"
        Dim c = New Child(p)
        Console.WriteLine("Property1 = ""{0}"", Field1 = ""{1}""", c.Property1, c.Field1)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Class Parent
        Public Property Property1 As String = "not set"
        Public Property Field1 As String = "not set"
    End Class

    Class Child
        Inherits Parent
        Public Sub New(myParent As Parent)
            Dim fieldInfo = GetType(Parent).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic _
                                                      Or BindingFlags.Instance)
            For Each field In fieldInfo
                field.SetValue(Me, field.GetValue(myParent))
            Next
            Dim propertyInfo = GetType(Parent).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic _
                                                             Or BindingFlags.Instance)
            For Each prop In propertyInfo
                prop.SetValue(Me, prop.GetValue(myParent))
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class

End Module
```

Output:

> Property1 = "abc", Field1 = "def"

This solution is automated, so you won't need to change anything when adding or removing properties and fields in the base class.

Comment: As I've said, I wouldn't want to do something like this because every time an edit is made to the parent class which changes its properties, all children implementing this will have to be modified too.

Comment: Then use Reflection to iterate over properties and fields (even private) and set everything found to the derived class.

Comment: Could you link me to an example or a link which explains this? I can only find c# ones

Comment: I'll write it up when I get to my desk in a bit

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example!

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is not casting. Have you ever heard the expression"to cast something in a different light"? It means to look at the same thing in a different way or to make the same thing look different. That is the exact way that the term "cast" is used in programming. When you cast, you do NOT change the type of the object but only the type of the reference used to access the object. If you want to cast from a base type to a derived type then the object you're referring to has to actually be that derived type. If it's not then you're not performing a cast but rather a conversion.

So, why can't you convert an instance of a base type to an instance of a derived type. Well, why would you be able to? Yes, it's something that might save writing a bit of code on occasion but does it actually make sense? Let's say that you have a base type with one property and a derived type that adds another property. Let's also say that that derived type has constructors that require you to provide a value for that second property. You're suggesting that the language should provide you with a way to magically convert an instance of the base class into an instance of the derived class, which would mean it would have to slow you to circumvent that rule defined by the author via the constructors. Why would that be a good thing?

Comment: Ok — since I don't know much about this I called it the wrong name. But as for the 2nd point, I'm saying that you should be able to convert a base class into the subclass by writing a new initialiser for the subclass which takes an instance of the base class as a parameter. I don't see how this is any different to how you might call `MyBase.New(...)` or `super.init(...)` (depending on the language) in the initialiser — you still are required to initialise any non-inherited variables in that initialiser, so you would have to provide a value for new properties.

Comment: @QuestionAsker: That's not *casting*, and it has nothing to do with *converting a base class into the subclass*. It's called *inheritance*, where (just as you do from your parents or grandparents), you **inherit** the assets of your ancestor. As I said, you need to get a better understanding of inheritance and polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

In general, because of this:

```
Class TheBase
End Class

Class Derived1 : TheBase
    Sub Foo()
    End Sub
End Class

Class Derived2 : TheBase
    Sub Bar()
    End Sub
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim myDerived1 As New Derived1
    ' cast derived to base
    Dim myTheBase = CType(myDerived1, TheBase) 
    ' cast base to derived?
    ' but myTheBase is actually a Derived1
    Dim myDerived2 As Derived2 = CType(myTheBase, Derived2)
    ' which function call would you like to succeed?
    myDerived2.Foo()
    myDerived2.Bar()
End Sub
```

Comment: I clarified what I meant in the OP — I meant conversion rather than casting. So after the conversion from Base to Subclass, only the properties belonging to the Base are carried over. Therefore `myDerived2.Foo` wouldn't exist.

Comment: The point here is the only object which has been constructed is a Derived1. It cannot be changed into Derived2 because they could potentially have many differences. You can write your own methods for doing this, everyone knows by now you aren't talking about casting.